# Heap Memory is growing while using akka-http for implementing web socker server

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using akka-http for implementing web socket server.

Following is the request handler code for it:

```
  def decodeService: Flow[Message, Message, _] = { 
    Flow[Message].map { 
      case BinaryMessage.Strict(encodeMsg) => 
        try {
          WebServer.getWorkerActor ! QueueWork(protoMsg(this, encodeMsg))
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => {
            println("[ERROR] failed to send BinaryMessage.Strict: " + e)
            TextMessage("[ERROR] failed receiving BinaryMessage.Strict")
          }
        }
        TextMessage("[INFO] BinaryMessage.Strict")

      case BinaryMessage.Streamed(streamedMsg) => {
        implicit val system = ActorSystem("DecoderSystem")
        implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
        val streamedMsgFuture: Future[Seq[ByteString]] = streamedMsg.runWith(Sink.seq)
        streamedMsgFuture.onComplete { completedStream =>
          var completeBytestring = new ByteStringBuilder()
          //I'm sure there's a better way to do this.. but hey, it's O(n)
          completedStream.foreach { x => 
            x.foreach { y => 
              completeBytestring ++= y  
            }
          }
          try {
              WebServer.getWorkerActor ! QueueWork(protoMsg(this, completeBytestring.result()))
          } catch {
            case e: Exception => {
              println("[ERROR] failed to send BinaryMessage.Streamed: " + e)
              TextMessage("[ERROR] failed receiving BinaryMessage.Streamed")
            }
          } finally {
            completeBytestring.clear()
          }
        }
        TextMessage("[INFO] BinaryMessage.Streamed")
      }

      case TextMessage.Strict(txt) => TextMessage("Succesfully receive text message")
      case _ => TextMessage("Message type unsupported")
    }
  }
```

My web server gets stream of data frequently every 1min. I have seen memory is growing. If I don't process Streamed messages, its able to hold. Also connection between client and server is persistent.

Have I used Flows/Sink/Source wrongly? How do flush stream?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, the most glaring problem is that you create an entire new `ActorSystem` for *each* streaming message you receive. An `ActorSystem` is like a thread pool for your actors; you want to create as few as possible of them, ideally only one for the entire application. And not only you create them for each message, you do not close them - all of the dispatchers configured in an `ActorSystem`, and all of the resources it holds will remain forever hanging. Of course, your memory usage will grow, if you receive lots of streamed messages.

Since you use akka-http, you are bound to have one `ActorSystem` where you invoke `Http().bind*`. You need to make it accessible inside the `decodeService` method. Also, the way you compute the combined byte stream seems overly complicated to me. Consider writing it like this:

```
def decodeService: Flow[Message, Message, _] = Flow[Message].mapAsync(4) {
  case m: BinaryMessage.Strict =>
    Future.successful(m)
  case BinaryMessage.Streamed(streamMsg) =>
    streamMsg.runReduce(_ ++ _).map(BinaryMessage.Strict)
  case m =>
    Future.successful(m)
}.map {
  case BinaryMessage.Strict(encodeMsg) =>
    try {
      WebServer.getWorkerActor ! QueueWork(protoMsg(this, encodeMsg))
      TextMessage("[INFO] BinaryMessage.Strict")
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) =>
        println("[ERROR] failed to send BinaryMessage.Strict: " + e)
        TextMessage("[ERROR] failed receiving BinaryMessage.Strict")
    }
  case TextMessage.Strict(txt) => TextMessage("Succesfully receive text message")
  case _ => TextMessage("Message type unsupported")
}
```

Here, first we transform all binary messages to `BinaryMessage.Strict`, and then we are processing them like in your original code. Note that you have to write the confirmation message inside the `try` block, because otherwise even if you have an exception, the successful message will be returned. Also, if you decide not to handle text messages at all, the code could become even simpler:

```
def decodeService: Flow[Message, Message, _] = Flow[Message]
  .filterNot(_.isText)
  .mapAsync(4) {
    case BinaryMessage.Strict(binary) =>
      Future.successful(binary)
    case BinaryMessage.Stream(binaryStream) =>
      binaryStream.runReduce(_ ++ _)
  .map { encodeMsg =>
    try {
      WebServer.getWorkerActor ! QueueWork(protoMsg(this, encodeMsg))
      TextMessage("[INFO] BinaryMessage.Strict")
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) =>
        println("[ERROR] failed to send BinaryMessage.Strict: " + e)
        TextMessage("[ERROR] failed receiving BinaryMessage.Strict")
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:

DescriptionResourcePathLocation Type
could not find implicit value for parameter materializer: akka.stream.Materializer

Comment: I have followed your second suggestion. As I dont handle text messages

Comment: "could not find implicit value for parameter materializer": that's what I meant what I said that you have to make the actor system and the materializer available to the `decodeService` method. You *necessarily* have them both if you're using akka-http, because you have to create a materializer in order to use the `Http().bind*` methods. Therefore, you already have created them somewhere; pass them in an appropriate manner to the `decodeService` method, and you will be good to go.

Comment: In your case I think the most succinct way would be to add `(implicit materializer: Materializer)` parameter to the `decodeService` method. If you then call this method from e.g. akka-http routes declaration, then it is very likely that you will have the materializer in scope there. But take this with a grain of salt because your application may be structured differently, and, for example, if you use some DI container, you may prefer passing the materializer using dependency injection.